# React displaying a widget received by an API thats formatted in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm fetching widgets from the spoonacular API and I receive a HTML response for the widget. Right now I'm trying to play with how to get this response to show up in my react component. This is a sample response:

```
<div>
   <canvas id="taste-visualization"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
   var config={type:"radar",data:{labels: 
   ["Sweet","Salty","Sour","Bitter","Savory","Fatty"],datasets:              
   [{label:"",backgroundColor:"rgb(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",borderColor:"rgb(75, 192, 
   192)",pointBackgroundColor:"rgb(75, 192, 192)",data: 
   [31.46,100,23.52,10.93,43.37,80.91]}]},options:{legend:{display:!1},title: 
   {display:!1},scale:{pointLabels:{fontSize:20},angleLines:{display:!0},ticks: 
   {display:!1,min:0,max:100,stepSize:20}}}};new 
   Chart(window.document.getElementById("taste-visualization") ,config);
<script>
```

I'm trying to display this html in react so I put the content between the script tags in dangerouslySetInnerHTML

```
<>
<div>
   <canvas id="taste-visualization"></canvas>
</div>
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `var config={type:"radar",data:{labels:["Sweet","Salty","Sour","Bitter","Savory","Fatty"],datasets:[{label:"",backgroundColor:"rgb(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",borderColor:"rgb(75, 192, 192)",pointBackgroundColor:"rgb(75, 192, 192)",data:[31.46,100,23.52,10.93,43.37,80.91]}]},options:{legend:{display:!1},title:{display:!1},scale:{pointLabels:{fontSize:20},angleLines:{display:!0},ticks:{display:!1,min:0,max:100,stepSize:20}}}};new Chart(document.getElementById("taste-visualization") ,config);`}}>
<script>
</>
```

But when I ran this code the widget didn't appear, I'm assuming it's because it can't read document.getElementById("taste-visualization"), but I'm not too sure if that's the reason why and I'm not sure how I can get this code to display in react. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Ideally you should be downloading JSON from the API and then use that to create the HTML. What's `Chart`?

Comment: I think for this endpoint specifically I receive a HTML response instead of a JSON response (https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Visualize-Recipe-Taste-by-ID). As for `Chart` it creates a chart with the features specified by config